# C Program Not Recognizing Constant From Header File

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I have the following really simple header file:

```
#ifndef __ZYNQ_CSORT_H__
#define __ZYNQ_CSORT_H__
#define CONSTANT    5
#endif
```

I am including this header file in another C file in the same folder. The preprocessor doesn't complain at all about the header file include, but when I try to print the value of the constant, it tells me that it is not defined. Anybody know what's up?

Comment: what is the actual error message.  Is this a compilation error or a run time error?  How are you trying to print the defined constant? You need to provide that source as well.

Comment: Also does gcc provide a pragma so that you can log a message into the compiler output to determine if the #define CONSTANT is being hit or not?  If so, make that change and let us know as well.

Comment: No one can help you until you provide a SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Comment: I would guess that you are including a different header from the one you're expecting. You can use `gcc -H` to list the actual header file names as they're included, which can be very informative. You could also add a `#error ZYNQ_SORT_H` line at the start of the file. Technically, names starting with an underscore and either another underscore or a capital letter are reserved for the implementation to use; it could be misbehaving because you're using reserved names, but it is pretty unlikely to be the problem (but you should still drop the leading double-underscore from the macro name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I'm uncertain about what the preprocessor is up to, I find it is often revealing to run the C preprocessor by itself. For example, given `test1.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H
/* In TEST1_H */
#define CONSTANT 5
#endif
```

... and `test1.c`:

```
#include "test1.h"
#include "test1.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return CONSTANT;
}
```

... running `cpp -C test1.c test1.c.out` (the `-C` argument makes the preprocessor retain comments) gives `test1.c.out` as follows:

```
# 1 "test1.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test1.c"
# 1 "test1.h" 1


/* In TEST1_H */
# 2 "test1.c" 2


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 return 5;
}
```

Thus, for my case I can be confident that the right header file is being included.

Answer (score 0):

CONSTANT would be undefined if __ZYNC_CSORT_H were already defined when this file was parsed.

Comment: I've tried removing the header guards as well if that's what you're referring to - same result.